# row / column rescaling of a "dgTMatrix"

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am currently working on a project that requires to multiply certain sparse matrices.

Working in R with the `Matrix` package I create matrices via commands like "Diagonal" or simply "Matrix", e.g.

```
A <- Diagonal(10)

B <- kronecker(Matrix(diag(10)),t((rep(1,10))))

C <- A%*%B
```

The matrix `A` is of class `dgTMatrix` while matrix `B` is of class `ddiMatrix`.

Is there any way to speed up the computation of the multiplication?

I am thinking of `RcppArmadillo` but I have no clue how to handle these classes and if it even performs better.

Comment: You might take a look at the `SparseM` package which allows for basic linear algebra operations on sparse matrices.

Comment: Sorry, dimension mismatch for this small example. Should work now.

Comment: In fact it is. I am just trying to say what I need regardless of the above example. So you can also pick any other example where the result is not obvious.